# i have a table in angular, i want to write a click event to change the vlaue of the cell that was clicked

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular2-template

here is my Template that makes the table

```
 <div class="container col-md-6 col-lg-6 container-fluid col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3">
    <h1 class="page-header">
        multiplication-table    <small>angular demo</small>
    </h1>

    <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <tr *ngFor="let i of matnumbers" class="text-center ">
            <td *ngFor="let j of matnumbers" class="text-center" (click)="showmul()">
                <span  *ngIf="showItem"> {{i*j}}</span>
                <span  *ngIf="!showItem"> {{i}}x{{j}}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

this is the component:

```
export class MultiplicationTable {
 matnumbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
 showmul() {
    var that = this;
    this.showItem = false;

    setTimeout(function () {
        that.showItem = true;
    }, 550);
    that.showItem = false;
 }
}
```

unfortunatly this code change the spans of all the cells in my table,
and i want to change only the specific one that was clicked.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the html
    
        
            multiplication-table    angular demo

```
    <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <tr *ngFor="let i of matnumbers" class="text-center ">
            <td *ngFor="let j of matnumbers" class="text-center" (click)="toggleNum(i,j)">
                <span *ngIf="shownNumbers.indexOf(i*10+j) != -1"> {{i}}x{{j}}</span>
                <span *ngIf="shownNumbers.indexOf(i*10+j) == -1"> {{i*j}}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

this is the component

```
export class MultiplicationTable {
 shownNumbers: number[] = [];
 matnumbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
 toggleNum(i: number, j: number) {
     var num = j +i* 10;
     var index = this.shownNumbers.indexOf(num);
     if (index != -1) {
         this.shownNumbers.splice(index, 1);
     } else {
         this.shownNumbers.push(num);
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export class MultiplicationTable {
 shownNumbers: number[] = [];
 matnumbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
 toggleNum(num: number) {
  var index = this.shownNumbers.indexOf(num);
  if(index != -1){
    this.shownNumbers.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
   this.shownNumbers.push(num);
  }
 }
}
```

In your html

```
<div class="container col-md-6 col-lg-6 container-fluid col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3">
<h1 class="page-header">
    multiplication-table    <small>angular demo</small>
</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered ">
    <tr *ngFor="let i of matnumbers" class="text-center ">
        <td *ngFor="let j of matnumbers" class=text-center"(click)="showmul(j)">
            <span  *ngIf="shownNumbers.indexOf(j) != -1"> {{i*j}}</span>
            <span  *ngIf="shownNumbers.indexOf(j) == -1"> {{i}}x{{j}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This might work

Comment: thank you very much, it was almost perfect answer the only problem was that it changed the all column and i wanted only the clicked cell ,but it gave me good direction. I shared the final code.

Comment: I see, I missed the part about your variable i.. :)